# do some math actions with strings in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have two-hour data they are as strings `let first = "09:15"` `let second = "10:15"` how can I do some math actions with these strings? for example I want to do `console.log(first - second)`

Comment: Try something like `first.split(":")` to get the hour and seconds separately, and then you can use  `parseInt()` to get it as a number.

Comment: That won't work when going below 0, or above 23 @bluecouch. Consider converting it to seconds, then do some math and convert back to hours and minutes.

Comment: @0stone0 yeah more work will be required to deal with the details of subtracting times, that was just getting the string to numerical. Converting to seconds would be a good strategy for the logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert them from String to Date using `Date.parseExact()` from date.js library

```
var dateString = "10:12";
var date = new Date.parseExact(dateString, "HH:mm");
```

and then you can use : `second.diff(first)`

Comment: Date.parseExact() is from date.js library

Comment: it converts the specified string of a date and time to its DateTime

Comment: Where was Date.js mentioned?

Comment: Sure will edit my answer

Answer (score 1):

```js
var dateString = "10:12";
var dateString2 = "10:20";
var startTime=moment(dateString, "HH:mm:ss a");
var endTime=moment(dateString2, "HH:mm:ss a");
var duration = moment.duration(endTime.diff(startTime));
var hours = parseInt(duration.asHours());
var minutes = parseInt(duration.asMinutes())-hours*60;
alert (hours + ' hour and '+ minutes+' minutes.')
       
       var result = endTime.diff(startTime, 'hours') + " Hrs and " +     
                        endTime.diff(startTime, 'minutes') + " Mns";
alert(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Also you can use MomentJS JavaScript library .